# Which form of nginx rewrite is more efficient?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, processing-efficiency

I have a bunch of redirects that were in .htaccess when I refactored my site.  Now I want to recreate them for nginx.  Are the following equivalent, and which style is more efficient?

```
# Style A
location / {
    location /foo/123/old {
        rewrite ^(.*) /bar/123/ permanent;
    }
    location /baz/456/old {
        rewrite ^(.*) /bar/456/ permanent;
    }
}

# Style B
location / {
    rewrite ^/foo/123/old\/?$ /bar/123/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/baz/456/old/\/?$ /bar/456/ permanent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on `nginx` own recommendation you should use a location block and a `return` directive

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

Comment: But that section on 'taxing-rewrites' is addressing passing the URL unchanged to a new host, sure return is more efficient just passing through the existing URI.  That doesn't say anything about matching in the 'location' vs. regex in the rewrite.